# return value of JS Constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, return

I feel like a beginner here. I don't quite get why this 2 codes behave differently. Can someone explain it please? I feel like i miss some JS mechanic here.

Code1:

```
function Car(){
    var miles = 0;    

    function drive(dist){
        miles = miles+dist;
    }

    return {
       drive:drive,
       miles:miles
   }          
}

var car = new Car;
car.drive(50);
```

Code2:

```
function Car(){
    var miles = 0;    

    function drive(dist){
        miles = miles+dist;
    }

    return {
       drive:drive,
       miles:function(){
           return miles;
       }
   }          
}

var car = new Car;
car.drive(50);
```

So it seams like for code1, JS creates a new scope/closure/whatever....value for miles. Maybe someone smart can provide some background to this behavior.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P7Zqv/

Comment: Since you have an explicit return value for the constructor function, you aren't really using it as a constructor function so you should give it a name that starts with a lower case letter and not call it with `new`.

Comment: In your fiddle: `milesA` is a not a pointer to `miles`. In your posted code: You have 2 closures in both cases, but in case A (_only_) you also have 2 distinct *variables* for `miles`: one internal, one external. In case B, you only have the internal `miles`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript copies by value.

In the first example:

1. The `miles` variable is `0`.
2. An object is returned with a `miles` property that has a copy of `0` in it.
3. The `miles` variable is updated (now `50`) .
4. The `miles` property is read (still `0`).

In the second example:

1. The `miles` variable is 0.
2. An object is returned with a `miles` property containing a function that returns the value of the `miles` variable.
3. The `miles` variable is updated (now `50`).
4. The `miles` function is called and returns the value of the `miles` variable (`50`).

Comment: so `miles:miles` will do a copy of the value and not a reference?

Answer (score -1):

the first code is returning the variable miles as it is, it is being updated but is not being read because it's in a closure, just as Quentin mentioned, the second code is returning a function that returns a variable known as a getter function in Javascript, you have made your own getter function that returns the updated value, you can read more about getter functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

in short the first code returns a variable miles and the second code returns a getter function miles() that returns the variable miles. I hope that helps :)

if you try something like this:

**CODE 3**

```
function Car()
{
    var miles = 0;
    function drive(dist)
    {
        return miles += dist;
    }

    return {
        drive: drive,
        miles: miles
    };
}
var car = new Car();
car.drive(50); // returns 50 and not undefined
```

this way when car.drive(50) is called, you will not get an undefined because the function is returning a value.